# Is there a way to bootstrap only the changed packages and their dependencies?

Tags: npm, monorepo, lerna

I am investigating the features of Lerna to try and speed up our bootstrap process which currently takes quite a long time.

> When referring to `bootstrap` here I am referring to the process of running `npm install` with hoisting and linking local packages together

One of the things I am trying to do is only build the packages that I have changed in a branch. Take this example project

```
Package CLI
Package Header
Package Footer
Package WebApp : Depends on Header & Footer
```

With this scenario what I want to do in CI is:

- If I only change the `CLI` project then only the `CLI` project should go through `bootstrap -> build -> test`
- Only changing `Header` should do the process for `Header`, `Footer` and `WebApp` because we want to ensure the dependency hasn't broken anything
- Only changing `Footer` should do the process for `Header`, `Footer` and `WebApp` because we want to ensure the dependency hasn't broken anything
- Only changing `WebApp` should do the process for `Header`, `Footer` and `WebApp` because we need to use the dependencies to check `WebApp`

The first thing I have looked at is using the [jobs affected by a PR](https://lerna.js.org/docs/features/run-tasks#run-tasks-affected-by-a-pr). This works for executing a script defined in the package.json, but only for the package itself and not its dependencies. In my example if I change `CLI` then the job only runs in the `CLI` package as I want, but if I change `WebApp` then it only runs in `WebApp` and it doesn't run on the dependencies `Header` and `Footer`. This is only for running an npm script rather than `bootstrap` anyway so I am not even sure this is the correct thing to be looking into.

Secondly I was looking into using [task pipelines](https://lerna.js.org/docs/getting-started#target-dependencies-aka-task-pipelines). So for example in the `package.json` of the `WebApp` I have

```
"dependencies": {
    "header": "*",
    "footer": "*"
}
```

And then in the `Lerna.json` I have

```
{
  "version": "3.0.0",
  ...
    "targetDefaults": {
        "build": {
            "dependsOn": [
                "^build"
            ]
        },
        "test": {
            "dependsOn": [
                "^build"
            ]
        }
    },
  "useNx": true
}
```

As far as I can tell though when I run test on `WebApp` using `$ npx lerna run test --scope=webapp` I can't see any output relating to it doing anything with it's dependencies. Additionally, I still think this doesn't account for the `bootstrap` process needed before the `build` step.

Comment: you can maybe look at the new `useNx` flag which uses caching and will only rebuild packages that changed, see [useNx - Wiki](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/main/commands/run#usenx-experimental)